# Can python metaclasses inherit?

Tags: python-3.x, metaclass

classes can inherit..

```
class Base:
    def __init__(self,name):
        self.name = name

class Derived1(Base):
    def __init__(self,name):
        super().__init__(name)


class Derived2(Base):
    def __init__(self,name):
        super().__init__(name)
```

Can a similar thing done for meta classes also?

I have a requirement where some of my classes will have to be both abstract base classes and also my own meta classes (say singleton types..)

Is it possible to do

```
class Singleton(type): 
   '''
   implementation goes here..
   '''

class AbstractSingleton(Singleton,ABCMeta):
   '''
   What code should go here??
   '''
```

If its possible how to implement the AbstractSingleton class?

Comment: Have you tried it? It should work. Your example metaclass is only more complicated than your normal classes because it uses multiple inheritance.

Comment: nope i havent.. i dont understand completely how the __new__ method call will be chained in case of metaclass inheritance and as i have asked i am not sure what code should go inside the AbstractSingleton..

Comment: As long as you're using `super` in both your metaclasses, it will probably just work.

Comment: Who is the one that suggests that you need metaclasses for singletons? 
That person  should be forbidden of writing any Python code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

But first things first:

You *should* not be using metaclasses for creating singletons in Python.
Singletons are a simple concept, and just a custom `__new__` method is enough - no need for a metaclass for that.

This simple 4 line *normal* class code can be used as a mixin, and will turn any derived classes into "singleton" classes - afer the first instance is created, no further instances are created, and the first instance is always returned:

```
class SingletonBase:
   def __new__(cls, *args, **kw):
        if not "instance" in cls.__dict__:
              cls.instance = super().__new__(cls, *args, **kw)
        return cls.instance
```

Now, if you'd have a real case for another metaclass and needed to combine that with ABCMeta or other metaclass, all you'd have to do is to create a third metaclass that inherits from both metaclasses - if both of them use `super` in a well behaved way, it would just work.

```
class SingletonMeta(type):
    def __call__(cls, *args, **kw):
         # You know - you _really_ should not be using metaclasses for singletons.
         if not "instance" in cls.__dict__:
             cls.instance = super().__call__(*args, **kw)
         return cls.instance


class SingletonAbstractMeta(SingletonMeta, abc.ABCMeta):
    pass

class SingleAbstractBase(metaclass=SingleAbstractMeta):
    ...
```

For sheer coincidence, earlier this week  I used exactly *this* use case as an example of what can be achieved with a "meta meta class" in Python. By having a special "meta meta class" to the metaclass one wants to combine to another (I even use ABCMeta on the example), it can create the derived combined metaclass just by using the operator " + ", like in

```
class SingletonMeta(type, metaclass=MM):
    ...

class AbstractSingletonBase(metaclass=SingletonMeta + abc.ABCMeta):
    # code here.
```

[Check the answer here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/476586/is-anyone-using-meta-meta-classes-meta-meta-meta-classes-in-python-other-lang/45873191#45873191)